# How to remove string that dosn't have an html tag using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to remove strings that do not have an `html` tag.

For example :

```html
<div class="A">
  <a href="#" class="link">keep this</a> and i want to remove this 
</div>
```

Can I do this using only css ?

Comment: you can't, since css isn't used for coding much, use js or jQuery instead

Comment: So far there are 3 people that disagree with this comment.

Comment: The CSS solution isn't strictly removing the text, just hiding it. But it is an innovative solution.

Comment: @durbnpoisn To be fair the title asks how to "remove" the string, not merely hide it.  You can't actually remove anything from the DOM using CSS. The OP should clarify the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you can use `font-size` ::

```css
.A {
  font-size: 0;
}
.A a {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <a href="#" class="link">keep this</a> and i want to remove this
</div>
```

Comment: I was just about to write exactly the same. Don't think there is another way.

Comment: Haha...  My answer is strikingly similar as well, but using color.

Comment: Yep @durbnpoisn same principle hide all .. show with target tags :)

Comment: Nice solution - love it when there's more than one solution to a question!

Answer (score 9):

You could use `visibility`:

```css
.A {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.A a {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <a href="#" class="link">keep this</a> and i want to remove this 
</div>
```

NOTE - of course this DOES NOT remove the string / element in question from the DOM itself, it merely hides it but achieves the same purpose.

Comment: I Love Programming =D great solution

Answer (score 5):

Set the style inside of class "A" to be blank by default.  Set up a secondary class to handle ".A a".  This will allow you to have two different styles.  One for anchored, one for not.

```
.A { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }  //Set this to transparent
.A a { color: #000 }
```

Something like that.

Comment: Didn't think of that way - nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `display: none` with the `:not()` pseudo-selector

```
.A :not(a) {
    display: none;
}
```

EDIT: This does not work

Neither does this:

```
.A {
    display:none
}

.A a {
    display: inline!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this with pure css. If you cannot change the markup, then you will need to use JS to grab the content you want to keep and remove the rest.

If you have any control over the markup you should really consider using different markup. You could have an alternate element that is initially hidden.

```
<div class="A">
    <a href="#" class="link">keep this</a> and i want to remove this
</div>
<div class="A hidden">
    <a href="#" class="link">keep this</a>
</div>
```

you could also enclose the other content you want to remove in a span tag and give it a class that you can reference later.

```
<div class="A">
    <a href="#" class="link">keep this</a> <span class="bad-stuff">and i want to remove this</span>
</div>
```